# Add and remove classes from Node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have a slider in my page and slider's indicators are dynamic, It bases on slider's elements' number and width of body.

My code block is:

```
function setIndicators(){
  const indicator = document.createElement("div");
  indicator.className = "indicator active";
  indicatorContainer.innerHTML = "";
  for(let i = 0;i <= maxIndex; i++){
    indicatorContainer.appendChild(indicator.cloneNode(true));
  }
  updateIndicators();
}
```

which is working fine. But I want to show active indicator but I cannot manipulate elements' classes.

I tried this:

```
function updateIndicators(index) {
  indicators.forEach((indicator) => {
    indicator.classList.remove("active");
  });
  let newActiveIndicator = indicators[index];
  newActiveIndicator.classList.add("active");
}
```

And I am not able to reach every indicators using index or anything I know/find. Also, it seems like NodeList not a HTML element.

Other things you may need:

```
const indicatorContainer = document.querySelector(".container-indicators");
const indicators = document.querySelectorAll(".indicator"); 
let maxScrollX = slider.scrollWidth - body.offsetWidth;
let baseSliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
let maxIndex = Math.ceil(maxScrollX / baseSliderWidth);
```

Comment: This code looks fine from the perspective you have done. Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: `const indicators = document.querySelectorAll(".indicator");` does not extend into the future. You have to move this line into `updateIndicators` (or use `let` and update it before using it). You also have `updateIndicators();` without an index argument, is that deliberate? Other than that, the code seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/67fh2dvk/

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisG. I moved const indicators = document.querySelectorAll(".indicator"); into the updateIndıcators(); and it's working now. If you can post it, I would like to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Eray Great, that's exactly what I corrected in my answer. Glad we found out the problem together.  Also one thing I wanna inform is - use the `.active` query so that it's lighter than `.indicator` query.

Comment: Thank you so much @PraveenKumarPurushothaman. I have `.active` classes in several parts of my html code (probably, more than indicators). I didn't want to remove all of them. Also, `indicator.className = "indicator active";` was my mistake, too. it's only `"indicator"`.

Comment: @Eray Gotcha... Yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better one I would suggest using the indicators in a different way. Since your HTML isn't shared, I have to assume a few things:

```js
function clearAll() {
  const activeOnes = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
  activeOnes.forEach(function(activeOne) {
    activeOne.classList.remove("active");
  });
}

function chooseOne(index) {
  clearAll();
  const indicators = document.querySelectorAll(".indicator");
  indicators[index].classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Operator Mono', consolas, monospace;
}

.indicators {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 15px;
}

.indicators .indicator {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.indicator.active {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="indicators"><div class="indicator">I1</div><div class="indicator">I2</div><div class="indicator">I3</div><div class="indicator">I4</div><div class="indicator">I5</div></div>
<button onclick="chooseOne(2); return false">Select I3</button>
<button onclick="chooseOne(3); return false">Select I4</button>
```

I would have done this differently this way.

**Preview**

[image: preview]